# Расширенный поиск

Tags: дефект, локализация, поиск

При выполнении [поиска сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20c%20-%D0%B2%20-%5Bc%5D%20closed%3Ayes%20duplicate%3Ano%20migrated%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20is%3Aanswer), часть страницы с отображением настроек поиска не локализована в должной степени:

> [image: параметры поиска]

1. Требуют перевода фразы из секции "параметры поиска".
2. "параметры поиска" следовало бы написать с большой буквы и поставить двоеточие в конце.
3. "not" для отсутствующих меток требует перевода.
4. Фразу "результатов найдено содержащие" следует заменить на "Показаны результаты содержащие:". В текущем виде фраза меняется для разного кол-ва результатов, но здесь это не нужно, т.к. кол-во выводится в другом месте страницы:

> [image: 50 результатов]

На MSE заведены связанные сообщения:

- [Advanced search options should be allowed to localize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291549/339911)
- [Search request options should use some kind of separation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303545/339911)

Answer (score 1):

То, что можно было сделать с помощью переводов Transifex - сделано:

> [image: поиск переведен как смогли]

Дальше - дело за разработчиками.