# Отсутствует перевод при поиске по пользователю и метке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:218063+%5Bwpf%5D)

Выводится:

> results found tagged with [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) search options **user 218063**

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3929/176217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На текущий момент исправлено:

> [image: Результаты поиска по метке]