# Непереведенная строка в поиске по меткам из профиля

Tags: дефект, локализация, поиск

Если зайти в свой профиль и на закладке "Активность" кликнуть на какую-нибудь метку в разделе "Метки", появляется сообщение:

> results found tagged with **oracle** search options **user 180398**

Вот прямая ссылка, где это видно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:180398+[oracle]

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но "окончательный ответ" скорее в этом сообщении: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6491/180398 Я так понимаю, существует специальный интерфейс для перевода, но в него попадает не всё. Что не попадает - остается непереведенным надолго.